# How to apply the commands in a batch file to a selected file from the context menu

Tags: batch-file, context-menu

I received the request to create a script that lives in the context menu to easily rename a file to the current date and time. I have been able to compose most of the script, but am stuck with the last line...

What I have so far is the batchfile that composes the date-time portion that will be used as the new filename:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%%ldt:~4,2%%ldt:~6,2%_%ldt:~8,2%%ldt:~10,2%%ldt:~12,2%
echo %ldt%
```

This results in `20210921_120738` which is what I want the filename to become. The echo %ldt% is for documentation purposes and is to be removed from the final script.

Next step in the script is the renaming of the file: something like `ren "selected file" %ldt%`

What I do not seem to be able to figure out is the last line in the batch file where you apply the renaming command on the selected file.

I have been trying variations of: `cmd /c for /f do ren "%1" %ldt%` but that did not work...

Comment: Why did you add "for /f do" in the command?

Comment: I'm absolutely not sure about the command so most likely as you mention it should not even be there...

Comment: Try with out. If there's still a problem, try to debug with a command like `echo "%1" %ldt% >\path\file.txt`.

Comment: I added:

echo "%1" >C:\script\file.txt
echo %ldt% >>C:\script\file.txt

to be able to see what each parameters output was.

The first line was: ""
The second line was: 20210921_152255

Comment: How did you setup the context menu?

Comment: Under HKCR\*\Shell I created a key called "Rename to date".
Under this key I created another key called "Command". The value of this key points to 'C:\\script\\rename.bat'

When I right-click a file, the command is listed. When I add 'pause' in my batchfile and echo the %ldt%, I can see the value in a command-line window. So it seems that part is working fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors:

- The context-menu command should be:

  ```
    C:\\script\\rename.bat "%1"
  ```
- The line inside the batch file should be:

  ```
    cmd /c ren "%1" %ldt%%~x1
  ```

Comment: Thanks ! This is progress...
When I rightclick a file and select the command from the contextmenu, the filename is changed into the date-time. I'm however loosing the extension of the file. So filexyz.txt becomes 20210921_173331

Comment: Rename syntax improved above. See [link](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Comment: Thanks harrymc, that resolved the issue !

Comment: As soon as my account is sorted out, I will upvote your answer - thanks.

Comment: Thanks - I just marked your answer as accepted. Upvoting your answer is not possible (yet) as I can't get my account verified: I never received the verification mail to verify my mail address (checked all possible folders) and because of that, I cannot set a password on the account. I contacted support but they have not reached out to me yet...

Comment: Can't you ask for a resend on the login page?

Comment: I did, and I am receiving the password recovery mails, but when I enter a new password it says the mail address has not been verified, so I'm a bit in a circle...

Comment: There was once a link for resending the verification email. Try with another browser on which you have never logged-in.

Comment: Thanks - used another browser, did a password recovery and managed now to create the account (no signs of any verification required). I have upvoted your answer. Thanks again!